# Linking external css file to XSLT won't apply

Tags: css, xml, xslt

## Edited question:

I am trying to link an external CSS file to an xslt file. My output will be in HTML and I am currently using a CMS tool called TeamSite to view the changes. I tried adding a head tag and a link tag to add it like how normally would in html setting, but no styling is being applied and no error message is being displayed either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html-entities SYSTEM "http://www.interwoven.com/livesite/xsl/xsl-html.dtd">
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:include href="http://www.interwoven.com/livesite/xsl/HTMLTemplates.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="http://www.interwoven.com/livesite/xsl/StringTemplates.xsl"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
                <link href="slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="TILES" select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@Name='Tile']/DCR/herotile"/>
        <section class="center slider">
            <xsl:for-each select="$TILES">
                <div style="border-color:blue; border-style: solid;">
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </section>

    <script type= 'javascript'>
      <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".center").slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          centerMode: true,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 4,
          centerPadding: '0'
        });
      })
      ]]>
    </script>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also tried copy pasting the whole css into xslt file to see if I have an incorrect file path, but still no luck.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .slick-slider
                {
                    position: relative;

                    display: block;
                    box-sizing: border-box;

                    -webkit-user-select: none;
                       -moz-user-select: none;
                        -ms-user-select: none;
                            user-select: none;

                    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
                    -khtml-user-select: none;
                    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
                        touch-action: pan-y;
                    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
                }

                .slick-list
                {
                    position: relative;

                    display: block;
                    overflow: hidden;

                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                .slick-list:focus
                {
                    outline: none;
                }
                .slick-list.dragging
                {
                    cursor: pointer;
                    cursor: hand;
                }

                .slick-slider .slick-track,
                .slick-slider .slick-list
                {
                    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                }

                .slick-track
                {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;

                    display: block;
                }
                .slick-track:before,
                .slick-track:after
                {
                    display: table;

                    content: '';
                }
                .slick-track:after
                {
                    clear: both;
                }
                .slick-loading .slick-track
                {
                    visibility: hidden;
                }

                .slick-slide
                {
                    display: none;
                    float: left;

                    height: 100%;
                    min-height: 1px;
                }
                [dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
                {
                    float: right;
                }
                .slick-slide img
                {
                    display: block;
                }
                .slick-slide.slick-loading img
                {
                    display: none;
                }
                .slick-slide.dragging img
                {
                    pointer-events: none;
                }
                .slick-initialized .slick-slide
                {
                    display: block;
                }
                .slick-loading .slick-slide
                {
                    visibility: hidden;
                }
                .slick-vertical .slick-slide
                {
                    display: block;

                    height: auto;

                    border: 1px solid transparent;
                }
                .slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
                    display: none;
                }
                .slider {
              width: 50%;
              margin: 100px auto;
          }
          .slick-slide {
            margin: 0px 20px;
          }
          .slick-slide img {
            width: 100%;
          }
          .slick-prev:before,
          .slick-next:before {
              color: black;
          }
            </style>
        </head>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Any idea how I can link an external css file?

Comment: Does your XSLT create HTML output? How about posting a minimal but complete sample that does not have the result you want, together with a detailed explanation as to how you use XSLT and how you look at the result to check whether the CSS in the result is applied? You current template creates a HTML structure with only a `head` element so I wonder where you want to see any CSS applied if there is no body with contents to style.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one template matching `/` (unless you use modes) so you will have to decide what to put in there, one approach is e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
                <link href="slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

then make sure you write the other template for an element in your document, for instance

```
<xsl:template match="Properties">

        <section class="center slider">
            <xsl:for-each select="Data/Datum[@Name='Tile']/DCR/herotile">
                <div style="border-color:blue; border-style: solid;">
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </section>

    <script type= 'javascript'>
      <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".center").slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          centerMode: true,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 4,
          centerPadding: '0'
        });
      })
      ]]>
    </script>
</xsl:template>
```

Or make sure your single template matching `/` creates the complete HTML document e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
                <link href="slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <section class="center slider">
            <xsl:for-each select="Properties/Data/Datum[@Name='Tile']/DCR/herotile">
                <div style="border-color:blue; border-style: solid;">
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </section>

    <script type= 'javascript'>
      <![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".center").slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          centerMode: true,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 4,
          centerPadding: '0'
        });
      })
      ]]>
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: can I not add the `<link href="slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in the second template u suggested, and just make it a one file?

Comment: I did not show any solution using multiple files, I only explained if you want to use several matching templates then you need to make sure they match different nodes (unless you wanted to use modes) and you need to make them interact with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. I have edited the answer and shown how to put your snippets into a single template.

Comment: I am not sure how you write and test your XSLT, I would suggest to use an editor with an XSLT plugin or an XML IDE where you can see the result document, that way it should become clear that your attempts so far don't create any meaningful complete HTML document structure. There is really no secret or problem in generating HTML with CSS from XSLT, if you know how to use HTML and CSS then it is only a task of generating the proper, complete HTML structure.